# How to use django-debug-toolbar on AJAX calls?

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm curious if there's a reasonable way to use the (amazing) django-debug-toolbar with AJAX queries.

For example, I use a jQuery $.get with a bunch of parameters to hit a Django URL and load it inline. If I have an error with that, it isn't registered on the toolbar. I also can't use it by copying the AJAX URL because DDT attaches to the body tag of the response, and it wouldn't make any sense to be including body tags with AJAX responses.

Any direction would be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same problem before!
And as I'm doing more and more AJAX heavy applications, I  released a [Django Application](https://github.com/recamshak/django-debug-panel) and a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/django-debug-panel/nbiajhhibgfgkjegbnflpdccejocmbbn) that together solved exactly that problem.

All the information is in the github repository.

Comment: Not sure why, but the Chrome extension seems to be unable to display debug information for Ajax calls (jQuery.get, jQuery.getJson, ...)

Comment: @PetrPeller did you install the latest django-debug-panel package ? The previous version had problem when clickjacking protection is activated. If it's still not working, could you please open an issue on github with more information (Django version, example of code, etc)

Comment: Installed using `pip install django-debug-panel` ... I will  try to investigate more and let you know on GitHub

Comment: Nice. @recamshak Have you considered merging your panel with the django debug toolbar project?

Comment: Yes! Fantastic solution. Years after posting, happy to accept this answer!

Comment: `django-debug-toolbar` is displayed both on the page and in Developer Tools. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: here in 2020 I couldn't get this working with Django 2.2 and the repo hasn't been updated for 4 years, the request history thing below works though

Answer (score 35):

### Update: this functionality is now built into django-debug-toolbar

It was added in this [PR](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/pull/1250) and released in version 3.0

#### The old answer may still be useful for older versions of the toolbar:

I wrote the [Request History Panel for Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/djsutho/django-debug-toolbar-request-history) that can be added to the Django Debug Toolbar to view requests other than the current one (including AJAX requests).

Install via pip:

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar-request-history
```

In **settings.py** add `'ddt_request_history.panels.request_history.RequestHistoryPanel'` to `DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS` e.g.:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'ddt_request_history.panels.request_history.RequestHistoryPanel',  # Here it is 
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel',
]
```

Comment: Awesome sauce - I am able to fire in from a python requests client (the real client for mine) then analyse and profile in DjDt. Brilliant stuff!

Answer (score 7):

I've hit this problem recently. My quick-n-dirty-but-working solution was just to add some HTML views to flex the same code.

So for example, if I can see in NewRelic that 90% of my website's time is spent in an ajax call to /search_for_book?title=, my code might look like this:

```
views.py:

def search_for_book(request, title):
    data = _search_for_book(title)
    return json_response(data)

def test_search_for_book(request, title):
    data = _search_for_book(title)
    return http_response(data)
```

The bottleneck will be somewhere in the **_search_for_book** code; whether we call it by ajax is irrelevant to diagnosing its inefficiencies (in my case, at least; YMMV)

Answer (score 4):

Ddt plugs itself into a response, which means that there is no standard way of browsing its panels for AJAX request. Also, AJAX response can be in JSON format, which makes it impossible for ddt to plug into it.

Personally I'd find a way of logging ddt output to a text file, or maybe it supports client-server architecture in which client works inside AJAX request handler and sends data to the server? I don't know what's possible as there are dozen ddt clones out there.

Comment: True, but most profilers and debuggers use headers to send the data from the server to the client (while still preserving a possible JSON response), and a browser extension to show it. It's been 3 years since your answer and DDT still doesn't have this functionality :)