# debugging long django reponse times due to unexpected db queries

Tags: django, profiling, django-views, response-time

I've used [this post](https://gun.io/blog/fast-as-fuck-django-part-1-using-a-profiler/) to profile a ajax django view with a json response. The following are by far the largest time suckers:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.502    1.502    1.502    1.502 c:\python27\lib\socket.py:336(read)
        1    1.501    1.501    1.501    1.501 c:\users\jonathan\virtual_environments\myapp\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py:119(connect)
        2    0.749    0.375    0.749    0.375 c:\users\jonathan\virtual_environments\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py:50(execute)
        1    0.245    0.245    0.245    0.245 c:\python27\lib\socket.py:406(readline)
        2    0.240    0.120    1.741    0.871 c:\users\jonathan\virtual_environments\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py:157(_cursor)
```

Hey, what's that?!? postgresql database access? But the view code doesn't even access the database!

```
@login_required
@debug_ajax
@json_error_on_exception
def my_ajax_view(request):
    json_response = redis_conn.get('precompiled-json-response')
    return HttpResponse(json_response, mimetype='application/json')
```

I checked the decorators and only the django auth native `@login_required` is suspect.
How can I debug this? How can I see the queries issued?
Even if auth does query the db, these response times are insane. How can I further drill down to see what's up?

Comment: Debug Toolbar is really helpful. As far as I remember, django does database operations at every request for the sites framework and the auth framework.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). And See the response times and sql query times.

Comment: I thought [Django Debug Toolbar doesn't support json ajax requests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5126825/348545)