# Django debug toolbar in Angular.js not working

Tags: angularjs, django, django-debug-toolbar

I want to use **Django debug toolbar** with **Angular.js** to see **SQL** queries, time taken to execute and explanation.
I have added  **Django debug toolbar** in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

According to documentation I set `ROOT_TAG_EXTRA_ATTRS = 'ng-non-bindable'` in the `settings.py` file. And even tried `ROOT_TAG_EXTRA_ATTRS = 'class="ng-non-bindable"'`

I see 0 SQL query even though queries are made and data is received successfully.

**What's the catch here?**

Comment: Have you succeed with setting up Angular and Django Debug Toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

It probably didn't work because `ROOT_TAG_EXTRA_ATTRS` should be set not directly in `settings` but within `DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG` dictionary:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'ROOT_TAG_EXTRA_ATTRS' : 'ng-non-bindable'
}
```

Update: chances are that with `angular` sql queries will still be not visible because `django-debug-toolbar` does not support `ajax` calls. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124975/how-to-use-django-debug-toolbar-on-ajax-calls?rq=1) might help - there is an answer referring to a Django app [django-admin-panel](https://github.com/recamshak/django-debug-panel) and an associated [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/django-debug-panel/nbiajhhibgfgkjegbnflpdccejocmbbn) that shoud support ajax calls. But the problem is that it looks like this project is not supported and I haven't been able to make it work with latest versions of `Django` and `django-admin-toolbar` yet.