# Using Django debug toolbar to profile POST responses

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

Django debug toolbar is a great tool to profile slow SQL queries - among other things. I'm able to do this for GET responses in my Django app. My question is: how do I profile (and optimize) my POST responses?

Comment: Hassan, can you make your question clearer? I've just tried DDT and it seems to work **equally as well with views using GET and POST**. The only thing that you may have to be careful about is if the POST view ends up with a redirect, but there's an "Intercept redirects" box to tick for that.

Comment: @raphv: hold on buddy, give me a sec

Comment: @raphv: Okay, so I think intercept redirects solved my problem. Most of the POST requests I was looking at were redirecting. And I hadn't ticked that option. You could leave that as an answer, and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: OK. I've made it an answer and added a bit about AJAX calls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django-Debug-Toolbar works the same with GET and POST requests.

However, one common UI design pattern is that successful form submissions lead to a redirect, which loads a new view and makes you lose all the SQL history in DDT.

If this is the case, one of the panels on DDT allows you to **intercept redirects** and inspect SQL queries at each step.

Also, if your problem comes from making AJAX calls, you should have a look at the answers to this question: [How to use django-debug-toolbar on AJAX calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124975/how-to-use-django-debug-toolbar-on-ajax-calls)